# The user is anonymous after returning from a redirect

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, 3d-secure

we implemented a paymentmethod with saved creditcards and 3dsecure (SAP commerce/hybris), but it's not always working. Sometimes a nullpointer for the orderData is thrown, after returning from the paymentservice. The reason for this seems to be, that the user sometimes is anonynoums after the return, so the orderData isn't visible.(the orderData exists by the way)

But I have no idea why this happens. And like I said it only happens occasionally on prod, but when I debbuged local it happend most of the time. And at the paymenservice the payment is authorized.

But it's difficult to debug, because there aren't any testcards to test with 3dscure, so I have to use a real one everytime.

To be honest, I am not sure if I am allowed to show the code here, so please forgive me, for not showing it now (I didn't write it).

Are there any "common" mistakes/suggestions/best-practices or whatever? Or maybe just an idea?

Oh, and we don't face this problem with other returns like paypal.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky, since I don't know the code, but here are some advices:

1. Maybe the Session Cookie in the browser is destroyed somehow? You can check with the Browsers developer tools if the cookie is contained in all requests (Network Tab -> Click on the Request -> Request Header). This can sometimes happen if you switch between http/https or multiple subdomains.
2. Bad timing with an automatic logout of the user?
3. Are you using multiple cluster nodes? Maybe the session is not yet synchronised between the nodes?

Comment: Thanks for the hints: 1.It seems like it's a problem with the sameSite attribute of the JSESSIONID cookie. Or at least I found similar topics concerning the default handling of the cookie in googlechrome, when the attribute isn't set. So it seems like we have do Update our Tomcat or set it with springsession if possible. The only thing which is still strange is, that it somestimes works, even in Chrome. And because of my local test I'm sure  point 2 +3 are not the case.